# Break log files after first occurrence of a string in unix

Tags: linux, unix

On a Unix server the log file has appended since long and now it size is 42 gb.

I have to check all logs for after the first occurrence of a particular date i.e: Nov 12 , 2018.

I need all logs for the date Nov 12, 2018. What is the best possible way to do it?

Comment: Do you want the only the first occurance of the date, all lines with data, or all lines with the date and the lines after this ?

Comment: All logs for this date

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are looking for `Nov 12 , 2018` text in the log file you can use `sed` to print everything after `Nov 12 , 2018` is matched:

```
sed -ne '/Nov 12 , 2018/,$ p' <path to log file>
```

If the date is always at the beginning of the line you can use `grep` with regex to filter out specific lines:

```
grep -e "^Nov 12 , 2018" <path to log file>
```

Comment: i need all logs for the date Nov 12 ,2018 please suggest

Comment: The date might be `Nov 12, 2018` depending on where the spaces are

Comment: Start of line is `^`, so `grep -e "^Nov 12 , 2018" <path to log file>`

Comment: @WalterA fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the logs for that specific date just do:

```
grep "Nov 12, 2018" file.log
```

Comment: It works for .out file as well ?

Comment: If it's a text file, yes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

grep -e "$Nov 12 , 2018" yourlogfile.txt > filteredlog.txt

make sure you match the date and year correctly.

Comment: You seem to have confused the start of line anchor (`^`) with the end of line anchor (`$`). And since you put that in double-quotes, the shell will try to expand the variable `Nov`, which is probably undefined. That will give you an empty string instead.